# spine, node.js (express) and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, spine.js

I'm developing an app on my local pc. THe frontend should be built with spinejs and the backend-api with node.js.
Spine is running on port 9294 and node.js is running on port 3000.
in Spine I've added to my model the following:

```
@url: "http:localhost:3000/posts"
```

and in my express server

```
app.get('/posts', function(req, res){
  console.log("giving ALL the posts");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.json(posts);
});
```

But I'm always getting the following erro in chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/posts. Origin http://localhost:9294 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What must I do that I can access my api properly? I though adding the header in the responses does fix the problem.

Comment: Have you inspected the response header to confirm that the header is indeed being set?  Also, jQuery uses the 'OPTIONS' HTTP command to detect pre-auth; make sure express is responding to that HTTP Verb as well

Comment: honestly it seems my request never reaches my node.js server. I've added a debug statement in app.get() BEFORE anything is sent to the client. When accessing my api directly over the url I can see the statement but not when accessing via spine

Comment: YOu should use something like charles to make sure this is happening.  We do a ton of x-domain stuff here and it's frustrating until you see that the header ISN'T being set.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`app.get` will only respond to `GET` requests. If the browser is preflighting it with an `OPTIONS` request, express will send an error because it doesn't have any listeners for those requests.  Try adding this code in addition to yours and see if it works:

```
app.options('/posts', function(req, res){
  console.log("writing headers only");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.end('');
});
```

Also note: if you're sending cookies with the request (`withcredentials=true`), then the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header cannot be `*`, it must be the exact value in the `Origin` header that the browser automatically adds to the ajax request like so:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
```

This is for security reasons - if you're doing something that requires cookies, then it is more likely that you will want to actually check that the `origin` is an allowed website in order to avoid [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 15):

This middleware will allow CORS using Express, the key is detecting the preflight request `OPTIONS` and returning a response to avoid 404's or duplicate database queries.
See resource: http://cuppster.com/2012/04/10/cors-middleware-for-node-js-and-express/

```
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
app.use(methodOverride());

// ## CORS middleware
// see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: methodOverride is no longer bundled with Express as of version 4, so you will need to include "method-override" in your package.json, then instead of `app.use(express.methodOverride())`, use `var methodOverride  = require('method-override'); app.use(methodOverride());`